# changing App_Start to AppStart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fxcop, stylecop

I have set up a new MVC 4 web application. I am currently running source code anaylsis against the project and getting the following error:

```
CA1707  Identifiers should not contain underscores
```

The reason for this is because of the namespace "App_Start" due to the App_Start folder name. Are there any issues with renaming the folder to "AppStart"? This will mean all my rules are passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suppress that rule for that particular namespace rather than rename it. Create a `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file in your web project root, and add this:

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

[assembly: SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming",
                           "CA1707:IdentifiersShouldNotContainUnderscores",
                           Scope = "namespace",
                           Target = "<namespace>.App_Start",
                           Justification = "This is an infrastructure namespace")]
```

Comment: I prefer to rename it to AppStart. Stupid Microsoft engineers.

Comment: Seems `App_Start` convention is used mainly by `NuGet`. See this: http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/mvc-4-and-the-app-start-folder